# Python re.sub with a flag does not replace all occurrences

Tags: python, regex

The Python docs say:

> re.MULTILINE: When specified, the pattern character '^' matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following each newline)... By default, '^' matches only at the beginning of the string...

So what's going on when I get the following unexpected result?

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """// The quick brown fox.
... // Jumped over the lazy dog."""
>>> re.sub('^//', '', s, re.MULTILINE)
' The quick brown fox.\n// Jumped over the lazy dog.'
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Look at the definition of [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])
```

The 4th argument is the count, you are using `re.MULTILINE` (which is 8) as the count, not as a flag.

Either use a named argument:

```
re.sub('^//', '', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Or compile the regex first:

```
re.sub(re.compile('^//', re.MULTILINE), '', s)
```

Comment: it would be better to have `re.compile('^//', re.M).sub('', s)`

Comment: you don't have to compile it if you tell python the flag that you are passing it

Comment: @pseudosudo the flags arguments was added in Python 2.7, which didn't exist when this answer was posted. I've added the information to the answer.

Answer (score 12):

```
re.sub('(?m)^//', '', s)
```

Comment: @MJM You don't need the `MULTILINE` flag in the function parameters, in this case. It already has the inline flag for multiline: `(?m)`

Comment: Nice one @mypetlion - gotya (y)

Answer (score 8):

The full definition of [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) is:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])
```

Which means that if you tell Python what the parameters are, then you can pass `flags` without passing `count`:

```
re.sub('^//', '', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

or, more concisely:

```
re.sub('^//', '', s, flags=re.M)
```

Comment: @agf Ah, I didn't think to look at the date.