# Case insensitive regular expression without re.compile?

Tags: python, regex, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

In Python, I can compile a regular expression to be case-insensitive using `re.compile`:

```
>>> s = 'TeSt'
>>> casesensitive = re.compile('test')
>>> ignorecase = re.compile('test', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> 
>>> print casesensitive.match(s)
None
>>> print ignorecase.match(s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02F0B608>
```

Is there a way to do the same, but without using `re.compile`. I can't find anything like Perl's `i` suffix (e.g. `m/test/i`) in the documentation.

Comment: You can find an excellent introduction to regular experssoins at: http://www.python-course.eu/re.php

Answer (score 853, accepted):

Pass `re.IGNORECASE` to the `flags` param of [`search`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search), [`match`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match), or [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
re.search('test', 'TeSt', re.IGNORECASE)
re.match('test', 'TeSt', re.IGNORECASE)
re.sub('test', 'xxxx', 'Testing', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: `re.match('test', 'TeSt', re.IGNORECASE)` might lead to `TypeError` when either of the attribute being `None`.  Using `try & except` to catch `TypeError` matching by first_string == second_string.
**Sample Code**
`def equal_ignore_case(first_string, second_string):
    try:
        return re.match(first_string, second_string, re.IGNORECASE) is not None
    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        return first_string == second_string`

[Demo Code](https://repl.it/FWih)

Comment: @Abhijeet You really shouldn't use try/except in that case. Just check if any of the strings are `None` first.

Comment: It's important to use the named argument `flags` for `re.sub` otherwise it passes `re.IGNORECASE` to the `count` argument (s. also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581/python-re-sub-with-a-flag-does-not-replace-all-occurrences)

Comment: or: `re.I` shorthand.

Comment: Older versions of re have to use RegexFlag to access IGNORECASE. 
 e.x.: `re.RegexFlag.IGNORECASE`

Comment: Why the hell in 2 first we dont need to use "flags=" BUT in sub we MUST ? 
Example of a dirty library.  Very poor compared to Perl/javascript/php regexp!! Re creates its own concepts of how to interpret Regular Expressions... a nightmare!!

Answer (score 156):

You can also perform case insensitive searches using search/match without the IGNORECASE flag (tested in Python 2.7.3):

```
re.search(r'(?i)test', 'TeSt').group()    ## returns 'TeSt'
re.match(r'(?i)test', 'TeSt').group()     ## returns 'TeSt'
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention the feature being added in any particular version (as opposed to, say `(?(condition)yes|no)` which it says was added in 2.4), so I expect it has always been available since the first version of the `re` module, which I think was added in 1.5. Basically since the beginning of time for all intents and purposes when it comes to Python.  It's documented about half way through the first section of this page: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: Here we go - I looked through the documentation for 1.5 and found it documented about 60% of the way down this page: https://docs.python.org/release/1.5/lib/node65.html#SECTION005210000000000000000 I also checked the 1.4 documentation, which made no mention of this feature. So I guess it was added in 1.5, when the `regex` module was deprecated in favor of the `re` module.

Comment: This is a nice solution as it does not require a flag. In my case I am storing search strings in Redis and this is really helpful.

Comment: For instance `[st for st in filter(lambda x: not search(r'(?i)Mac', x), ['macintosh','tomato','MacMahon', 'and', 'maCaroni', 'pasta'])]` will filter out all those [Mm][Aa][Cc] matches and only leave us with `['tomato', 'and', 'pasta']`

Comment: @Private: conceptually it does set the re.I flag on the *entire* regex - not just the capture group it precedes. Be aware that `re.match(r'''A ((?i)B) C''', "a b c").group(0)` causes case-insensitive matching on everything (A and C), not just on B! If you only want case-insens matching on a specific capture group, this isn't the droid you're looking for.

Comment: @Private: yes totally. My point is conceptually it's the same as setting a flag. On the entire regex. Even the groups that precede it(!). There is no syntax to say "case-insensitive on the following capture groups only".

Comment: @smci I think this should be edited in the answer itself.

Answer (score 94):

The case-insensitive marker, `(?i)` can be incorporated directly into the regex pattern:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'This is one Test, another TEST, and another test.'
>>> re.findall('(?i)test', s)
['Test', 'TEST', 'test']
```

Comment: Better option, makes the regex portable across platforms and intent is clear at declaration

Comment: This `'(?i)'` approach also has the advantage that you can create a list of regexp's, some of which are case-insensitive and some are not.  (And of course, you can map `re.compile` over that list if you like.)

Comment: @SinaMadani I'm confused. How is that more portable than `flags=re.IGNORECASE`?

Comment: @RomainVincent more portable as you can just copy-paste the pattern itself and use it somewhere else. I'm not yet sure if I like this approach though.

Comment: @RoboRobok Ah yes, I didn't think about it this way. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 25):

You can also define case insensitive during the pattern compile:

```
pattern = re.compile('FIle:/+(.*)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: In the question OP uses this and asks whether there's another way to do it.

Comment: Helpful for the fast-scrolling ones.

Answer (score 16):

In imports

```
import re
```

In run time processing:

```
RE_TEST = r'test'
if re.match(RE_TEST, 'TeSt', re.IGNORECASE):
```

It should be mentioned that not using `re.compile` is wasteful. Every time the above match method is called, the regular expression will be compiled. This is also faulty practice in other programming languages. The below is the better practice.

In app initialization:

```
self.RE_TEST = re.compile('test', re.IGNORECASE)
```

In run time processing:

```
if self.RE_TEST.match('TeSt'):
```

Comment: Thank you! No one ever talks about compile, yet it's the smartest option!

Comment: The OP literally asks for a solution that _doesn't_ use `re.compile()`....

Answer (score 13):

To perform case-insensitive operations, supply re.IGNORECASE

```
>>> import re
>>> test = 'UPPER TEXT, lower text, Mixed Text'
>>> re.findall('text', test, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
['TEXT', 'text', 'Text']
```

and if we want to replace text matching the case...

```
>>> def matchcase(word):
        def replace(m):
            text = m.group()
            if text.isupper():
                return word.upper()
            elif text.islower():
                return word.lower()
            elif text[0].isupper():
                return word.capitalize()
            else:
                return word
        return replace

>>> re.sub('text', matchcase('word'), test, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'UPPER WORD, lower word, Mixed Word'
```

Answer (score 12):

For Case insensitive regular expression(Regex):
There are two ways by adding in your code:

1. `flags=re.IGNORECASE`

   ```
   Regx3GList = re.search("(WCDMA:)((\d*)(,?))*", txt, re.IGNORECASE)
   ```
2. The case-insensitive marker `(?i)`

   ```
   Regx3GList = re.search("**(?i)**(WCDMA:)((\d*)(,?))*", txt)
   ```

Answer (score 5):

```
#'re.IGNORECASE' for case insensitive results short form re.I
#'re.match' returns the first match located from the start of the string. 
#'re.search' returns location of the where the match is found 
#'re.compile' creates a regex object that can be used for multiple matches

 >>> s = r'TeSt'   
 >>> print (re.match(s, r'test123', re.I))
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='test'>
 # OR
 >>> pattern = re.compile(s, re.I)
 >>> print(pattern.match(r'test123'))
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='test'>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to replace but still keeping the style of previous str. It is possible.

For example: highlight the string "test asdasd TEST asd tEst asdasd".

```py
sentence = "test asdasd TEST asd tEst asdasd"
result = re.sub(
  '(test)', 
  r'<b>\1</b>',  # \1 here indicates first matching group.
  sentence, 
  flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

**test** asdasd **TEST** asd **tEst** asdasd

Answer (score 1):

`(?i)` match the remainder of the pattern with the following effective flags: i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': ["TeSt"] })
>>> r = s.replace(to_replace=r'(?i)test', value=r'TEST', regex=True)
>>> print(r)
      a
0  TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `(?i:string_region_to_ignore_case)` rather than `(?i)`. This method allows one to deal with case sensitivity in a more picky yet clear manner. For instance:

```
rex = re.findall (r'J(?i:ohn) S(?i:mith)',
      "John smith ; JOHN SMITH; john Smith; John Smith")
#Result:
['JOHN SMITH', 'John Smith']
```