# how to split very long regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

i have a regular expression which is very long.

```
 vpa_pattern = '(VAP) ([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}): (.*)'
```

My code to match group as follows:

```
 class ReExpr:
def __init__(self):
    self.string=None

def search(self,regexp,string):
    self.string=string
    self.rematch = re.search(regexp, self.string)
    return bool(self.rematch)

def group(self,i):
    return self.rematch.group(i)

 m = ReExpr()

 if m.search(vpa_pattern,line):
    print m.group(1)
    print m.group(2)
    print m.group(3)
```

I tried to make the regular expression pattern to multiple line in following ways,

```
vpa_pattern = '(VAP) \
    ([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}):\
    (.*)'
```

Or Even i tried:

```
 vpa_pattern = re.compile(('(VAP) \
    ([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}):\
    (.*)'))
```

But above methods are not working. For each group i have a space () after open and close parenthesis. I guess it is not picking up when i split to multiple lines.

Comment: What about simpler regex like `(VAP) ((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}) (.*)`?

Answer (score 8):

Look at [re.X flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.X). It allows comments and ignores white spaces in regex.

```
a = re.compile(r"""\d +  # the integral part
               \.    # the decimal point
               \d *  # some fractional digits""", re.X)
```

Comment: +1 And it should also be noted that Python's `r"""raw multi-line string"""` syntax (used here) makes writing these self-documenting regexes much easier (because it completely avoids any backslash soup confusion).

Answer (score 3):

Python allows writing text strings in parts if enclosed in parenthesis:

```
>>> text = ("alfa" "beta"
... "gama")
...
>>> text
'alfabetagama'
```

or in your code:

```
text = ("alfa" "beta"
        "gama" "delta"
        "omega")
print text
```

will print

```
"alfabetagamadeltaomega"
```

Answer (score 1):

Its actually quite simple. You already use the `{}` notation. Use it again. So instead of:

```
'([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}):'
```

which is just a repeat of `[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:` 6 times, you can use:

```
'([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){6}'
```

We can even simplify it further by using `\d` to represent digits:

```
'([\dA-Fa-f]{2}:){6}'
```

> **NOTE:** Depending on what `re` function you use, [you can pass in re.IGNORE_CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500864/case-insensitive-python-regular-expression-without-re-compile) and simplify that chunk down to `[\da-f]{2}:`

So your final regex is:

```
'(VAP) ([\dA-Fa-f]{2}:){6} (.*)'
```

Comment: A repeating group only captures the last repetition. Instead, use a repeating non-capturing group inside a capturing group. Note also that OP's regex does not capture the last colon.

Comment: If the OPs regex doesn't capture the final `:` then what is the `:` here: `'...[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}): (.*)'` doing?

Comment: The `()` define a group which the OP accesses as `m.group(2)`. The last `:` is outside the paretheses.

Comment: I see. They'll both recognize the same strings, though it seems the group structure may be different.