# Find all upper,lower combinations of string in Python

Tags: python, string, find

I want to search a string in each line of a list, it will match every case of UP/LOW combination possible

For example: If i type in "all" and it will search "all" "All "ALL" "aLL" "aLl" ... etc. It works like advanced search in text document i think.

More detail : if `'all'` was input, then any of these strings appear in that line will return FOUNDED : `'all', 'alL', 'All', 'ALL', 'aLL', 'aLl', 'AlL', 'ALl'`

Here is how i done with correct string find

```
string = "all"
line[i].find(string)
```

if the `line` was "ALL" , the result was `not found`, so this is a limitation.

Comment: can you just lowercase `line[i]`? and see if `all` is there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive Python regular expression without re.compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500864/case-insensitive-python-regular-expression-without-re-compile)

Comment: @depperm Yes it'd be done but I must keep the integrity of data so anyway else

Comment: you could create a copy and lowercase the copy and check....

Comment: You can convert the line and the search to the same case: `line[i].lower().find(string.lower())`. It doesn't change the original strings as they are immutable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate all combinations of lower and upper characters in a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775110/how-to-generate-all-combinations-of-lower-and-upper-characters-in-a-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of achieving that. Here they are:

**1. Changing the case of the string you are searching into:**

```
line[i].lower().find(string.lower())
```

or

```
line[i].upper().find(string.upper())
```

Here we're abusing of the immutability of the original strings, since they won't be changed although we apply `.upper()` to them, since we're not doing any assignment.

**2. using the `re` module would also be helpful:**

```
import re
re.search('all', line[0], re.IGNORECASE)
```

or

```
re.search('(?i)all',line[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, the IGNORCASE is what i'm looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! Please ask any other questions about this if something is still unclear

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> lines = ['All', 'ALL', 'all', 'WALL', 'BLAA', 'Balls']
>>> for line in lines:
...     if 'all' in line.lower():
...         print(line)


All
ALL
all
WALL
Balls
```

Comment: who downvoted and why? while not necessarily the best solution this is a valid solution

Comment: Of course, you can use comprehension: ```print([l for l in line if 'all' in l.lower()])```

Comment: @depperm I didn't downvote, but code only answers are discouraged and also searching for a duplicate might have been better

Comment: But it's a simple solution in the code and nothing extra.

Comment: so it will only find the lower case, i want to search in UPPER case too, like i type in "all", the line was "ALL" but result is "1 line found" or return index

Comment: It finds the uppercased strings as well @FederalReserve

Answer (score 1):

Try with list comprehension,

```
In [25]: line = ['All', 'ALL', 'all', 'WALL', 'BLAA', 'Balls']

In [26]: [i for i in line if 'all' in i.lower() ]
Out[26]: ['All', 'ALL', 'all', 'WALL', 'Balls']
```