# How to generate all combinations of lower and upper characters in a word?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you generate all combinations of lower and upper characters in a word? e.g:

`'abc'`  →  `['abc', 'ABC', 'Abc', 'ABc', 'aBC', 'aBc', 'abC', 'Abc']`

`'ab'` → `['ab', 'AB', 'Ab', 'aB']`

Comment: I have a feeling you're "doing this backwards" and generating all possible capitalizations unnecessarily.  That being said, you could generate all the possible capitalizations with with recursion (each letter is either upper case or lower case -- recurse on both) or or something like `itertools.product([(c.lower(), c.upper()) for c in word])`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve this by [zipping](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) the upper and lower case letters and taking their cartesian [product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

chars = "abc"
results = list(map(''.join, itertools.product(*zip(chars.upper(), chars.lower()))))

print(results)
>>>['ABC', 'ABc', 'AbC', 'Abc', 'aBC', 'aBc', 'abC', 'abc']
```

---

To visualise how this works:

1. `zip` is creating our 3 'axes' for us, each with 2 points (the upper / lower cases)
   `[('A', 'a'), ('B', 'b'), ('C', 'c')]`.
2. `product` takes the cartesian product of these axes, i.e. the 8 possible coordinates corresponding to the corners of the unit cube it creates:

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| 1. Create axes | 2. Take Cartesian product |

Answer (score 2):

Using recursion:

```
def foo(word):
    if len(word) == 1:
        return [word.lower(), word.upper()]
    else:
        return [f"{j}{i}" for j in foo(word[0]) for i in foo(word[1:])]

s = "abc"
print(foo(s))
```

```
>>> ['abc', 'abC', 'aBc', 'aBC', 'Abc', 'AbC', 'ABc', 'ABC']
```