# Python how to validate user input with multiple acceptable options

Tags: python

“C”, “c”, “coffee” or ANY combination of upper and lower case letters
that correctly spells “coffee”, i.e., “Coffee”, “COFFEE”, “coffEE” are acceptable, if doesn't meet requirement program ends, or else the program continues.

Comment: `if input_str.lower() == 'coffee'`

Comment: `if input().lower() in ('c', 'coffee'):`

Comment: In this case, the suggested answers and comments would work, but if the condition gets complicated enough to warrant the use for regular expression, [then there's a flag to ignore casing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500870/8557739).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.lower()` to make the input lowercase for a case-insensitive match:

```
import sys
expected = 'coffee'
if input('What do you want? ').lower() not in (expected[0], expected):
    sys.exit()
print('Right. Continuing...')
```