# Python Old Regex.casefold to Python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have been updating an old (from 1999) Python script to Python 3. Occasionally I have found [`regex.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1/lib/Contents_of_Module_regex.html#l2h-6845). It is typically used in something like:

```
some_var = regex.compile(pattern, regex.casefold)
```

How would I go about changing this so it works in the latest Python 3?

Comment: [case insensitive flag for regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500864/case-insensitive-python-regular-expression-without-re-compile)

Comment: @PatrickArtner I did a whole lot of searching but never found that. Thanks

Comment: you can still use re.compile .. simply add `re.I` or inline the case insesitivity in your pattern:  `r'(?i)+pattern`