# RegEx for matching strings with spaces and words

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have the following string:

> the quick brown fox abc(1)(x)

with the following regex:

```
(?i)(\s{1})(abc\(1\)\([x|y]\))
```

and the output is

> abc(1)(x)

which is expected, however, I can't seem to:

1. use \W \w \d \D etc to extract more than 1 space
2. combine the quantifier to add more spaces.

I would like the following output:

> the quick brown fox abc(1)(x)

from the primary lookup "abc(1)(x)" I would like up to 5 words on either side of the lookup. my assumption is that spaces would demarcate a word.

**Edit 1:**

The 5 words on either side would be unknown for future examples. the string may be:

> cat with a black hat is abc(1)(x) the quick brown fox jumps over the
> lazy dog.

In this case, the desired output would be:

> with a black hat is abc(1)(x) the quick brown fox jumps

**Edit 2:**

edited the expected output in the first example and added "up to" 5 words

Comment: _"I would like 5 words on either side"_ Where are those five words in your desired output?

Comment: the expected output for this specific example is clear, but if you gave another sentence I wouldn't know what would you want to extract. Please clarify what you're trying to do (focus on the _what_ not on the _how_)

Comment: Also what regex flavor (or programming language) are you using?

Comment: thanks - I have placed an edit in my original question to address these questions

Comment: @qbbq So, do you mean that you want _up to_ five words on each side? It's still not clear to me why the expected output of the first example starts with "quick" and not "the". Can you please clarify?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed yes up to five words - its a typo from my side, I will amend this in the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:[0-9A-Za-z_]+[^0-9A-Za-z_]+){0,5}abc\(1\)\([xy]\)(?:[^0-9A-Za-z_]+[0-9A-Za-z_]+){0,5}
```

Note that I've changed `\w+` to `[0-9A-Za-z_]+` and `\W+` to `[^0-9A-Za-z_]+` because depending on your locale / Unicode settings `\W` and `\w` might not act the way you expect in Python.

Also note I don't specifically look for spaces, just "non-word characters" this probably handles edge cases a little better for quote characters etc.
But regardless this should get you most of the way there.

BTW: You calling this "lookaround" - really it has nothing to do with "regex lookaround" the regex feature.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
(?:\w+[ ]){0,5}(abc\(1\)\([xy]\))(?:[ ]\w+){0,5}
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W5f64m/1)**.

**BreakDown:**

```
(?:               # Start of a non-capturing group.
    \w+           # Any word character repeated one or more times (basically, a word).
    [ ]           # Matches a space character literally.
)                 # End of the non-capturing group.
{0,5}             # Match the previous group between 0 and 5 times.
(                 # Start of the first capturing group.
    abc\(1\)      # Matches "abc(1)" literally.
    \([xy]\)      # Matches "(x)" or "(y)". You don't need "|" inside a character class.
)                 # End of the capturing group.
(?:[ ]\w+){0,5}   # Same as the non-capturing group above but the space is before the word.
```

**Notes:**

- To make the pattern case insensitive, you may start it with `(?i)` as you're doing already or use the [`re.IGNORECASE` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500870/4934172).
- If you want to support words not separated by a space, you may replace `[ ]` with either `\W+` (which means non-word characters) or with a character class which includes all the punctuation characters that you want to support (e.g., `[.,;?! ]`).