Regex to find digits not immedidately after certain word?
How to find invoice number from different companies which may have different order of invoice number, unit cost and total cost?
Following is specific example of a company XYZ which I need to get 1234545
This is invoice from company XYZ - 1234545 product name , product number 444456, information invoice unit cost $12.0 and invoice total $1343.00
Another company may have following invoice
This is invoice from company ABC - 1234545 product name and information invoice total cost $6777 and invoice unit cost $654
I tried this regex
(?<=invoice).+\d+ 

but it did not work.

It is something like invoice.*?(\d+)

What environment are you using? How do you mean "... not immediately after a certain word.."? To get the first number after first invoice, try ^.*?\binvoice\D+(\d+) info (your .+ is greedy btw.)

what if the company name is all digits , ie 123 or 456 ... . , is the structure always '.*company COMPANY_NAME - INVOICE_NUMBER ....' ?

Given the examples, try (?<=- )\d+

Regular expressions are rarely a good way to parse free-form text like this.

and if the invoice number is INV-24-06-0014 or 2024/INV/00235 ?

Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60452867/5527985

For me the solution was
XYZ.*?(\d+)

.  The Dot Matches any character except line breaks.
* Quantifier to match 0 or more of the preceding token.
? Lazy. Makes the preceding quantifier lazy, causing it to match as few characters as possible.
( Capturing group #1. Groups multiple tokens together and creates a capture group for extracting a substring or using a backreference
\d Digit. Matches any digit character (0-9).
+ Quantifier to match 1 or more of the preceding token.#regex
Apple Numbers RegEx support \K which is Perl format? PCRE?

Yes, \K is a PCRE escape sequence (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions). It's always helpful to mention the environment (tool you're using) along with regex-questions as flavors differ.
