# How to use re.findall to find a string I want?

Tags: python

I am using `re.findall('^company conformed name: .@([^])',lin')` to try to find the company name which is showing in the picture. Could anyone help me with this? This is a txt file and the company name I am looking for is after "Company conformed name:".[image]

Comment: What is the '.@' in your regex supposed to be doing? Looks wrong. Try removing it and repost your results.

Comment: Also, `re.findall()` is case-sensitive unless you use `re.IGNORECASE` flag, so 'company conformed name:' isn't going to match uppercase unless you add that flag.

Comment: Related: [Case insensitive regular expression without re.compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500864/case-insensitive-regular-expression-without-re-compile)