# Writing a regex expression that finds 'zz' in a word but not at the start and the end

Tags: python, regex

I am having some difficulty writing a regex expression that finds words in a text that contain 'zz', but not at the start and the end of the text. These are two of my many attempts:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?!(?:z){2})[a-z]*zz[a-z]*(?!(?:z){2})')
pattern = re.compile(r'\b[^z\s\d_]{2}[a-z]*zz[a-y][a-z]*(?!(?:zz))\b')
```

Thanks

Comment: you can just slice the start and end off `string[2:-2]`

Comment: Can you please clarify what the input looks like? I think some have (mis)understood that you are matching against individual words instead of whole sentences or word lists. You’ll get different answers if you are matching “dazzle” vs “buzz\ndazzle zap razzle”

Comment: Imagine having a text in a book and trying to find words that meet the criteria I listed. Jan already provided a solution. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: What about a word with several occurences of zz: azzazza, azzzzza ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte they are accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the direct translation would be

```
\b(?!zz)(?:(?!zz\b)\w)+zz(?:(?!zz\b)\w)+\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/hO4nEK/1/).

---

Programmatically, you could use

```
text = "lorem ipsum buzz mezzo mix zztop but this is all"

words = [word 
         for word in text.split()
         if not (word.startswith("zz") or word.endswith("zz")) and "zz" in word]

print(words)
```

Which yields

```
['mezzo']
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/TxKS5t).

Comment: Yeah very logical to assume that xD

Answer (score 3):

Another idea to use [*non word boundaries*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

> `\B` matches at any position between two word characters as well as at any position between two non-word characters ...

```
\w*\Bzz\B\w*
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9bZFqx/2)

---

Be aware that above matches words with *two or more* `z`. For *exactly two*:

```
\w*(?<=[^\Wz])zz(?=[^\Wz])\w*
```

[Another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Bh7wsm/1)

---

Use any of those patterns with `(?i)` flag for [caseless matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500864/case-insensitive-regular-expression-without-re-compile) if needed.

Comment: Very good idea, +1!

Comment: I tried your method as well but it detects words that have 'zz' at the end and at the beginning which is not wanted

Comment: @shillos Have you tried the demos? Should actually work :) and thank you @Jan!

Comment: Good to read your answers again :-)

Comment: @4th Bird, I'm happy about your comment, very kind!

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookarounds:

```
\b(?!zz)\w+?zz\w+\b(?<!zz)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/lveqVg/2)

or not:

```
\bz?[^\Wz]\w*?zz\w*[^\Wz]z?\b
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/lveqVg/1)

Limited to ASCII letters this last pattern can also be written:

```
\bz?[a-y][a-z]*?zz[a-z]*[a-y]z?\b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead and negative lookbehind assertions in the regex.

```py
>>> import re
>>> text = 'ggksjdfkljggksldjflksddjgkjgg'
>>> re.findall('(?<!^)g{2}(?!$)', text)
 ['gg']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria just means that the first and last letter cannot be `z`. So we simply have to make sure the first and last letter is not `z`, and then we have a `zz` somewhere in the text.

Something like

```
^[^z].*zz.*[^z]$
```

should work