# Python efficent non cases sensitive match?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python to check if 'apple' appears in another string we do:

```
if 'apple' in my_str:
```

To check without cases sensitive I read we can do:

```
if 'apple' in my_str.lower():
```

But what if `my_str` is REALLY long, it's not efficent to call `.lower()` on it... Doesn't python support native non cases sensitive match?

Comment: why isn't it efficient?

Comment: You can use the regex case insensitivity flag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655164/regex-ignore-case-sensitivity

Comment: @Sayse Consider something extreme like `my_str = "apple" + "x" * 1000000`. There's no need to construct a new megastring (literally) just to find out the first 5 characters of the original match.

Comment: @chepner - oh yea I get that, I was trying to get the op to explain their issue more… I.e where does the string come from (would you use a file stream and find the first character perhaps). What does the string look like or can the data be modified before. Would “pineapple” be acceptable etc. the accepted answer using findall still traverses the whole string rather than short circuiting and there’s almost certainly duplicates to this and didn’t want to just apply the first one I saw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions and `re.IGNORECASE` In python [Case insensitive regular expression without re.compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500864/case-insensitive-regular-expression-without-re-compile)

```
import re
s = 'padding aAaA padding'
print(bool(re.findall("aaaa",s,re.IGNORECASE)))
```

Prints True.