# python re.sub non-greed substitute fails with a newline in the string

Tags: python, regex

I've struck a problem with a regular expression in Python (2.7.9)

I'm trying to strip out HTML `<span>` tags using a regex like so:

`re.sub(r'<span[^>]*>(.*?)</span>', r'\1', input_text, re.S)`

(the regex reads thusly: `<span`, anything that's not a `>`, then a `>`, then non-greedy-match anything, followed by a`</span>`, and use re.S (re.DOTALL) so `.` matches newline characters

This seems to work unless there is a newline in the text. It looks like re.S (DOTALL) doesn't apply within a non-greedy match.

Here's the test code; remove the newline from text1 and the re.sub works. Put it back in, and the re.sub fails. Put the newline char outside the `<span>` tag, and the re.sub works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
text1 = '<body id="aa">this is a <span color="red">test\n with newline</span></body>'
print repr(text1)
text2 = re.sub(r'<span[^>]*>(.*?)</span>', r'\1', text1, re.S)
print repr(text2)
```

For comparison, I wrote a Perl script to do the same thing; the regex works as I expect here.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$text1 = '<body id="aa">this is a <span color="red">test\n with newline</span></body>';
print "$text1\n";
$text1 =~ s/<span[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span>/\1/s;
print "$text1\n";
```

Any ideas?

Tested in Python 2.6.6 and Python 2.7.9

Comment: Another identical issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581/python-re-sub-multiline-caret-match. This issue is rather common. The answer is: read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 4th parameter of [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is a `count`, not a `flags`.

> ```
> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)¶
> ```

You need to use keyword argument to explicitly specify the `flags`:

```
re.sub(r'<span[^>]*>(.*?)</span>', r'\1', input_text, flags=re.S)
                                                      ↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

Otherwise, `re.S` will be interpreted replacement count (maximum 16 times) instead of `S` (or `DOTALL` flags):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.S
16

>>> text1 = '<body id="aa">this is a <span color="red">test\n with newline</span></body>'

>>> re.sub(r'<span[^>]*>(.*?)</span>', r'\1', text1, re.S)
'<body id="aa">this is a <span color="red">test\n with newline</span></body>'

>>> re.sub(r'<span[^>]*>(.*?)</span>', r'\1', text1, flags=re.S)
'<body id="aa">this is a test\n with newline</body>'
```

Comment: Thanks @falsetru, that solved it. (Phew!)

Interesting side-note, the flags param isn't recognised in Python 2.6, so it's just as well we're using 2.7