# Python re.search behavior with beginning of line

Tags: python, regex

I have a simple string test as follows:

```
test = 'Liquid marinade for cooking fish liquid vegetables'
```

I want to match the keyword 'liquid marinade' in the string using regular expressions. (I match other keywords and need to use word boundaries, so a simple `string.index()` will not suffice)

I compile the following regex:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b(liquid marinade)\b')
```

Then do a case insensitive search:

```
regex.search(test, re.IGNORECASE)
```

And get nothing.

Same if I try with `^(liquid marinade)\b`.

Using `\b(marinade for)\b` matches the 2nd and 3rd word, so I'm guessing the problem comes from the fact that the string starts with the word `Liquid` but shouldn't that be covered by `\b` as a word boundary ?

Comment: The second argument to `regexObj.search` is a position from which you start searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That works

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b(liquid marinade)\b', re.IGNORECASE)
print(regex.search(test))
```

The `re.IGNORECASE` parameter that you passed to `search` is in fact the start position.

Having been caught a lot of times in `re.sub` as well (a classic issue: [Python re.sub with a flag does not replace all occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581/python-re-sub-with-a-flag-does-not-replace-all-occurrences)), I suggest that when you're adding flags you're using the `flags` keyword, not *positional passing* as there may be other options in the `re` methods (start position, count, you name it):

```
flags=re.IGNORECASE
```

If it works (like in `re.sub` or `re.compile`), then okay, and if it's not supported you get (like here):

```
regex.search(test,flags=re.IGNORECASE)  # wrong but explicit!
TypeError: 'flags' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

At least it doesn't do something else...