# How to overcome error "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern" in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Could anyone tell me why this is not working in Python?

```
s = "conversion of hotel into 16no managed flats"
re.sub("((?<=\d\w|\w\d)|(?<=\d))(\s*NO\.|NO\s)", " no ", s, re.IGNORECASE)
```

It's working in `https://regex101.com/` with Python engine selected.

I've overcame the look-behind fix length issue but not quite.

Comment: Change `re.IGNORECASE` to `flags=re.IGNORECASE`, see https://ideone.com/X6Dwvb

Comment: Thanks, it's working but what's the issue? Arguments mismatch?

Comment: Yes. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42597/3832970).