# Python: bug in re (regex)? Or please help me understand what I'm missing

Tags: python, regex

Python 3.9.18. If the basic stuff below isn't a bug in `re` then how come I'm getting different results with what's supposed to be equivalent code (NOTE: I am not looking for alternative ways to achieve the expected result, I already have plenty such alternatives):

```py
import re
s = '{"merge":"true","from_cache":"true","html":"true","links":"false"}'
re.sub(r'"(true|false)"', r'\1', s, re.I)
'{"merge":true,"from_cache":true,"html":"true","links":"false"}'
```

^^^ note how only the 1st and 2nd `"true"` were replaced, but the 3rd and 4rd are still showing quotes `"` around them.

Whereas the following, which is supposed to be equivalent (`(?i)` instead of `re.I`), works as expected:

```py
import re
s = '{"merge":"true","from_cache":"true","html":"true","links":"false"}'
re.sub(r'(?i)"(true|false)"', r'\1', s)
'{"merge":true,"from_cache":true,"html":true,"links":false}'
```

^^^ all instances of `"true"` and `"false"` were replaced.

Comment: You're passing `re.I` as the `count` parameter by accident. Use a named argument instead: `flags=re.I`. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) for reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Python re.sub with a flag does not replace all occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581/python-re-sub-with-a-flag-does-not-replace-all-occurrences)

Comment: FWIW, I caught the problem myself by noticing that the matching isn't case-sensitive at all, which made me think `re.I` was a red herring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `re.sub()` has the following signature:

```
Signature: re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

If you give `re.I` as the fourth argument, it will interpret it as the count argument.

When converted to an integer, `re.I` is equal to 2.

```
>>> print(int(re.I))
2
```

So supplying this flag in this way causes it to make only 2 replacements.

Instead, I suggest using a keyword arg.

```
re.sub(r'"(true|false)"', r'\1', s, flags=re.I)
```

Comment: Damnit. I feel so stupid. I need ample sleep.

Comment: This question has been asked many times. You should be voting to close as a dupe, not answering.

Comment: @Nick Okay. Thanks for letting me know. I apologize for not knowing every question which has previously been answered.

Comment: Fair enough, and hence I don't downvote, just make suggestions.